# how to call view controller with navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have one view controller  called login VC with navigation view controller.And i connect two button in my LoginVc.First button will navigate to signUp Screen as push segue.Second button will navigate to forgot password screen as push segue.

Now when user logged in and enter in to my app means.There is one button name called Log out.I have written the code functionality like, when user press log out button one uialert pop up will ask "Do You want to log out".If user press they will navigate to again login screen .

So after user pressed log out and if user came to login screen and if user press my two button [ i. e means forgot password screen, sign up screen button].Then i am getting crash.

Crash report :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

My log out button code :

```
@IBAction func LogoutButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout Successful", message: "You have successfully logged out.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action -> Void in

            let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController




            let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController


            })

        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })




}
```

I try adding this line :

```
let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! UINavigationController
```

But i am getting same problem.Now how can i re write my code in my log out button action method.To redirect to login screen with navigation bar.

Please help me out.Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the RootViewController to a ViewController but your application is NavigationViewController. Your RootViewController should be a NavigationController. So add your LoginViewController to NavigationViewController and set that rootViewController of window.

```
let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do like this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController!, animated: true)
```

and when you want to come back:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462

Comment: can you post some example code which will navigate with navigation controller with my login scren

Comment: It is in the answer above, check tutorial to understand this logic.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error there is no navigation controller found in your view hierarchy.

Select your loginViewController from story board and from `Editor` `embed in` `Navigation controller`. and use `performSegue` to push viewcontroller and use `popViewController` or `popTorootviewcontroller` to go back in navigation controller.

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Click to viewController in storyBoard
2. Go to **Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller** this will add navigation on this view controller.
3. Then you can push and pop from one view controller to another view controller.

Ex : **Push**

```
var dash : XyzViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("xyz") as! XyzViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dash, animated: true)
```

**Pop**:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVC") as! yourViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)